# Assign output of mkdir command to variable

Tags: shell, mkdir, mkdirs

I am trying to assign the output of mkdir command to a variable. So I can use the directory further.

```
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/user/ravi/myscripts/tmpdata
-bash-4.1$ OUTPUT=$(mkdir tmpbkp.`date +%F`)
-bash-4.1$ ls | grep tmp
tmpbkp.2017-04-06
-bash-4.1$ echo "$OUTPUT"
```

But the directory name is not assigning to the variable. Could you please correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run the mkdir command by itself, look how much output it produces:

```
$ mkdir foo
$
```

None!

When you use a command substitution to generate the argument to mkdir, look how much extra output you get:

```
$ mkdir tmpbkp.`date +%F`
$
```

None!

When you put it inside `$()` it still produces no output.

There is a `-v` option for mkdir (in the GNU version at least) which produces some output, but it's probably not what you want.

You want the name of the directory in a variable? Put it in a variable first, then call mkdir.

```
$ thedir=tmpbkp.`date +%F`
$ mkdir $thedir
$ echo $thedir
tmpbkp.2017-04-06
$
```