# Issue in mkdir output to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Hi Can any one help me to clear problem to assign the mkdir command output to Variable.

While execute the script I am able to create the directory with following command

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n " Which Name needs to create? (y/n): "; read dom       


     if [ "$dom" == "y" ]; then
    echo -n " Type an Domain name: " ; read domTemp

path=/home/rakesh/$domTemp

a=`mkdir -p -- "$path"`

echo "$a"

fi
```

By reading documents and stack issue, I know how to assign linux command to variable in shell script but the mkdir command not give expected result by printing $a and my expectation is to use the variable $a is to set the path in next command in the scrip.

```
/home/rakesh/foo.com
```

My intention is to collect the exact path of created directory to a variable. Though I can use the path to assign permission in further steps

Below solution is to make directory from variable only
[Assign output of mkdir command to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254508/assign-output-of-mkdir-command-to-variable)

Appreciate your knowledge on this.

Comment: `not give expected result` What do you expect? I would expect `a` to be empty.

Comment: `mkdir` never writes to `stdout`. So the value of `a` will always be null string after a=\`mkdir -p -- "$path"\`

Comment: What's the difference from the [question linked by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254508/assign-output-of-mkdir-command-to-variable)? To me that looks like an _exact_ duplicate? (with pretty much the same answer)

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, why do you think it's expected for mkdir to print anything on stdout? What part of its documentation says it _should_?

Comment: @knittl can you run the above scrip from your end and see what is the difference

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, nobody but you has a `/home/rakesh`, so nobody but you can run your script exactly as-given.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy accepted your suggestion, but please edit the above script with your any of folder and then run n see what its give you. Now I understood mkdir can't stdout after reading you referral link. If this post deleted from SOF  person like me waist time for search the possibilities in internet.

Comment: If `path=/home/rakesh/foo.com`, why do you need a `$a` at all? I still don't understand the point of this question in the first place. I don't know what running the code in the question is supposed to show me; just because I can see what the output _actually is_ doesn't mean I know _what you want_.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

```
mkdir_output=$(mkdir -v -p "$path")
```

**NB:** the `-v` option does the difference.

**Edit:** as stated by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) in the below comment, you could emulate the `-v` option by:

```bash
mkdir_output=$(mkdir -p "$path" && echo "Successfully creted folder \"$path\".")
```

Comment: Note that `-v` is not guaranteed by POSIX to be present: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html -- thus, tools that need to be portable across different UNIXlike operating systems should not rely on it.

Comment: As you suggested I updated my code but it print like **mkdir: created directory '/var/rakesh/foo.com'**  expect some valuable information like you suggest

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, what other information do you think is supposed to exist?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I expect like other commands mkdir can also assign to a variable. let me read your suggested post

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, `variable=$(somecommand)` writes the output of `somecommand` to `variable`. But if that command _has no output_, it's completely normal for the variable to be empty. An expectation that every command will have output is frankly wrong; that's not how UNIX works: the normal convention is that when a command (which doesn't have a specific job of producing output) works correctly it's silent; and if it has only informational or status output meant for humans, that goes to stderr not stdout so it isn't captured by command substitutions or pipelines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got solution by reading your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script/1371283#1371283  Works as expected :)

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, that solution answers a very different question than the one you appeared to be asking here, so I'm confused about the relationship between the two.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy by reading that answer i got solution by move that maked directory and pwd to take the output to variable. So I got the exact location **a=$(mkdir -v -p  "$path")

cd $path
d=$(pwd)
echo $d** my intention is to get maked directory path to a variable

Comment: @RakeshVijayan You already have this directory in the variable `path`. Do you suspect `mkdir` will create a directory different from the `$path`? No, it won't!

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, so what you want is the _absolute path_ of the directory, with symlinks replaced with the names they point to? You don't need output from mkdir from that; `path=$(readlink -m "$path")` on systems with GNU readlink. You can do that successfully even before the `mkdir` has happened, at a point in time when the directory doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @RakeshVijayan, ...by the way, the fact that we had to do all this back-and-forth question-and-answer to figure out what you were really asking for in your question (assuming that my current understanding _is_ in fact correct) is part of why I don't think this question would be helpful to others if left in the knowledge base in its current state; if it's not obvious to existing readers what the question is trying to determine how to accomplish, why would it be obvious to future ones?